# Gtk+3 How to set cursor on a Gtk.TreeView row?

Tags: gtk3, gtktreeview

I'm using Python3 and Gtk+3. 
When I add a new row to my Gtk.TreeView, these are always appended at the end.
I want whenever I add a new row to set the cursor on it.
I know I have to use the "set_cursor()" function, or at least I think so. However, I don't know how to retrieve the path of the row.

I am using the signal size-allocate, which tells me when there are changes in my Gtk.TreeView.

```
self.treeview.connect('size-allocate', self.on_treeview_size_changed)

def on_treeview_size_changed(self, widget, allocation):
    self.treeview.set_cursor(path, None, False)
```

Any ideas how can I retrieve the path of the last row or make what I am trying to do happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
        last = self.store.iter_n_children ()
        last = last -1  #iter_n_children starts at 1 ; set_cursor starts at 0
        c = self.treeview.get_column(0)     
        self.treeview.set_cursor(last , c, True)    #set the cursor to the last appended item
```

Basically, get the row count of the store, subtract 1 and set the cursor to that row.